# Manipulating button's class via javascript causing " are you sure you want to leave this page?" browser message

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with an `<input id='button' type='submit' class='button class1 class2'>` control.
When I press the button the page is submitted and the user is redirected to another view. This works fine.

I added a checkbox to the page, that changes the styling of the button mentioned above.

```
    $("#checkbox").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var button = $("#button");
            button.removeClass('class1 class2');
            button.addClass('class3 class4');
        }
    });
```

When I manipulate the classes of the button by changing the checkbox and then I press the button, I get a message from the browser "are you sure you want to leave this page?". If I do not manipulate the class of the button, any changes I make to the form do not trigger this message.

Any ideas on what may be happening?

Comment: You probably have an autopostback set to true on your checkbox... but I'm saying this knowing webforms, I'm not sure if .NET MVC has this type of functionality but it really looks like you're submitting the page or pointing to another one...

Comment: perhaps better to include your class definitions as well.

Comment: `window.unload` is triggered. check for the unload event on your page